# Java Methodについて

Tags: java

以下のようなコードを書いてみたのですが、コンパイラーエラーが表示されます。

> error: constructor Point in class Point cannot be applied to given types;

というエラーが28行目に表示されるのですが、なぜでしょうか？
解説お願いします。

```
class Point{
  private double x;
  private double y;
  public void constructor(){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      Point p = new Point(2.0, 5.0);
  }
  public double getX(){
    return x;
  }
  public double getY(){
    return y;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "<Point(" + x + "," + y + ")>";
  }
  public void translate(double dx, double dy){
    x = x +dx;
    y = y + dy;
  }
  public double distance(Point other)
  {
    Point that = (Point) other;
   double dist= Assignment1_7.distance(this.x, that.x, this.y, that.y);
    return dist ;
  }
  public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(this == other){
      return true;
    }
    if(other instanceof Point){
      Point that= (Point) other;
      return(this.x==that.y && this.y==that.y );
    }
    else
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

次の行で、存在しないコンストラクターを呼んでいるからです。

```java
Point p = new Point(2.0, 5.0);
```

おそらく、以下のようなコンストラクターが必要です。

```java
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

意図は分かりませんでしたが、`constructor()`というメソッドは、このクラスにはおそらく不要だと思います。